# how to read and sum all files' data asynchronously via async/await

Tags: node.js, async-await

I know bluebird or fs-promise or even es6 promise can do it. Like below I've done.

But I want to use the latest es7 async/await to achieve. I just don't get how to use async/await in a for loop(and then sum their results).

Most examples I googled are about fetch/ajax.get. But what I want is to read files and sum data together.

May someone have a hint? Thanks.

```
var fs = require("fs");
var Promise = require("promise");


function readDir(){
    var p = new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readdir( ".", function( err, files) { 
            resolve(files);
        })
    } );
    return p;
}



function readFile(file){
    var p = new Promise( function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.readFile( file, function( err, data) { 
            console.log("Successfully read a file.", file);
            resolve(data);
        })
    } );
    return p;
}



readDir().then(function(files){
    var promises = [];
    for ( var i = 0; i < files.length; i++ ) {
        promises.push( readFile(files[i]) );
    }

    Promise.all( promises ).then( function(results) {
        var totalBytes = 0;
        for ( i = 0; i < results.length; i++ ) {
            totalBytes += results[i].length;
        }
        console.log("Done reading files. totalBytes = " + totalBytes);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

First of all to use async/await we'll need Promises anyway. Just because unlike promises we cannot `await` callback-based functions.

So to get it started I suggest using bluebird's `.promisifyAll` method so all `fs` methods followed with 'Async' postfix will return promises.

At minimum you'll have:

```js
'use strict';

const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));

async function readFile(file) {
    let data = await fs.readFileAsync(file);
    console.log('Successfully read a file.', file);

    return data;
}

async function getTotalBytes() {
    let files = await fs.readdirAsync('.');

    //Making a promise for each file to read it.
    let promises = files.map(f => readFile(f));
    //Reading all in parallel
    let results = await Promise.all(promises);

    //Using native .reduce to sum the bytes
    let totalBytes = results.reduce((memo, r) => {
        return memo + r.length;
    }, 0);

    console.log('Done reading files. totalBytes = ' + totalBytes);
    return totalBytes;
}

//Running out function
getTotalBytes()
    .then(bytes => console.log(bytes))
    .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

There is an issue with this code. It will throw an error on attempt to `.readFile` a directory. So we could filter the directories out like this:

```js
async function getTotalBytes() {
    let files = await fs.readdirAsync('.');
    let promises = [];
    for (let file of files) {
        let stat = await fs.statAsync(file);
        if (!stat.isDirectory()) {
            promises.push(readFile(file));
        }
    }

    let results = await Promise.all(promises);
    let totalBytes = results.reduce((memo, r) => {
        return memo + r.length;
    }, 0);

    console.log('Done reading files. totalBytes = ' + totalBytes);
    return totalBytes;
}
```

Comment: you can use util.promisify, instead of addinng a package. More details here https://zeit.co/blog/node-8